# Finding Boolean/Logical Expressions for truth tables

Tags: logic

I need to find the Boolean expression for the truth table below where $P$, $Q$, $R$ are inputs, and $S$ is the output. Does anyone have a cool easy way of solving such problems please? Your help will be appreciated.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c||c}
P & Q & R & S\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is what you gave meant to be interpreted? I would have guessed that each `xxx y` is meant to be that the row corresponding the the assigments `xxx` has `y` as the output, but you have **four** variables (P, Q, R, and S), and only three inputs.

Comment: Thanks @Quanta. @Arturo, yes, I have 3 inputs and 1 output, S

Comment: While boolean algebra and discrete mathematics would fit, logic is really the proper tag. Mathematical physics? Not at all...

Comment: Karnaugh map (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) is the simplest way to go.

Comment: Looks to me like your expression is just $\text{if}(P, R, Q)$.

Comment: For the lazy people: [dcode](https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-truth-table) has a tool doing this for you. enter the results column as a string like "0001" and get a logical expression...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mechanical way of getting an expression that has a desired truth table is to take the disjunction of the formulas that determine the rows you want with 1s.

For example, for a truth table on P, Q, and R that has
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c||c}
P & Q & R & \text{Table}\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}$$
we note that the rows corresponding to $1$s are: $P\land Q\land R$, $P\land \neg Q\land R$, $\neg P\land Q\land R$, and $\neg P\land Q\land\neg R$. So a formula that has the desired truth table is
$$(P\land Q\land R)\lor (P\land\neg Q\land R)\lor (\neg P\land Q\land R) \lor (\neg P\land Q\land \neg R).$$
This is, of course, unlikely to be the *simplest* formula that works, and may be simplified later.

Comment: This can by easily simplified, for example the $$(P \land Q \land R)$$ and $$(P \land \neg Q \land R)$$ clauses only differ by the $$Q$$ and $$\neg Q$$ so they can be condensed to a single $$(P \land R)$$. This is the type of simplification that the Karnaugh map does for you.

Comment: Note: this is also a very convenient way to write a formula in disjunctive normal form.

Answer (score 4):

You can just render the thing as a bunch of OR-ed together clauses, one checking for each case where the output is 1. If you want a simpler expression, you can use a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: If you do the Karnaugh map the resulting expression is $$(P \land R) \lor (\neg P \land Q)$$

Answer (score 2):

Try a free program called Logic Friday...works standalone...you push new truth table, the number of inputs, then it creates a generic tt with all zeros out. Then you double click on each output you want to change to 1. Then you push Truth Table-->Submit and it will give you the Boolean. Then you push Equation-->Factor to get the factored Boolean.